# What are the required permissions to Approve a record

Tags: approval-process, profile

I am submitting a record to Approval through Apex code. I want to check if the User has the access to Approve record. Does the User needs to have edit access on that record?

Comment: You first need to understand the business use case before you can create an approval process. Are you using roles? Do you have any code you can show us? Is this a dynamic approval? What "rules" are you using to base the approval on and what triggers it? Is it time based? I recommend you look at Chapter 9 of [Force.com Platform Fundamentals][http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/adg_workflow_approvals.htm?].

Answer (score 3):

Read permission on the record - [Salesforce help article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_processing_approval_requests_parent.htm&type=5)

> To respond to an approval request from within
>   Salesforce:   Read on the associated record
>
> To respond to an approval
>   request from an email:    API Enabled

Answer (score 0):

Minimum Read permission on object. If you are a admin then you can approve any record. If you have read permission and if approver assigns you as a delegate approver then also you can approve it.